# how to move fragment to activity using navigation graph?

Tags: android

I'm dev-ing using fragment navigation. it's working well when moving fragment to fragment. But the problem comes when moving fragment to activity. I tried writing code about activity in nav_graph. but not working. So I retried at activity class adding 
setNavigationItemSelectedListener. fragment to activity working well, but don't work fragment to fragment. how to solve this problem? I want to move fragment to fragment and fragment to activity.

*nav_graph*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:startDestination="@+id/homeFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="com.haii.loginproject.fragment.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="Home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_secondFragment"
            app:destination="@id/secondFragment" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/secondFragment"
        android:name="com.haii.loginproject.fragment.second.SecondFragment"
        android:label="Second"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_second">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_secondFragment_to_homeFragment"
            app:destination="@id/homeFragment" />
    </fragment>

<!--

    <activity
        android:id="@+id/loginActivity"
        android:name="com.haii.loginproject.login.LoginActivity"
        android:label="Login"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_login">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_loginActivity_to_homeFragment"
            app:destination="@id/homeFragment" />

    </activity>
-->



</navigation>
```

*activity*

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        setupNavigationDrawer()
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_fragment)
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration
            .Builder(R.id.homeFragment, R.id.secondFragment,R.id.loginActivity)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawerLayout)
            .build()

        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)

        navigation_view.setupWithNavController(navController)


        navigation_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            when(it.itemId){
                R.id.loginActivity->{
                    var intent = Intent(this,LoginActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
            }

            true
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can navigate from fragment to activity just like you do for fragment to fragment but first you have to add activity as destination in navigation graph

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_loginActivity_to_homeFragment)
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to navigate from one activity to another without hosting a Fragment by using ActivityNavigator.

```
ActivityNavigator(this)
                    .createDestination()
                    .setIntent(Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java))
                    .navigate(null, null)
```

Comment: where I should this code? and I can't use this code. .navigate() is red line